# teUnable to mount NTFS partition

Tags: mount, windows-10, ntfs, nvme

I have an SSD with Windows 10 installed. I have been able to mount the partition in the past.

However, now, when I mount the partition with Windows on it, I get an error message complaining about a wrong file system type.

I have already disabled fast startup.
I am using Ubuntu bionic.
The output when I tried `ntfsfix`:

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/nvme0
```

> Mounting volume...
> Error reading bootsector: Invalid argument Failed to sync device /dev/nvme0: Invalid argument
> FAILED Attempting to correct errors...
> Error reading bootsector: Invalid argument
> Failed to sync device /dev/nvme0: Invalid argument
> FAILED Failed to startup volume: Invalid argument
> Error reading bootsector: Invalid argument
> Unrecoverable error Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.

And of

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/nvme0n1p3
```

> ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo ntfsfix /dev/nvme0n1p3 Mounting volume...
> NTFS signature is missing. FAILED Attempting to correct errors...
> NTFS signature is missing. FAILED Failed to startup volume: Invalid argument
> NTFS signature is missing. Trying the alternate boot sector
> Unrecoverable error Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.

`Chkdsk` on Windows doesn't report any problems.

Comment: Please explain more specifically, provide more information about the errors you got and where you get them. Answering the following question could be helpful to solve the problem.
1. Where do you get the error? and what the error is?
2. What the format of your removable disk is?

Comment: You need to make sure Windows is shut down and not hibernated. There is a setting for that in Power Options called Fastboot.

Comment: @mikewhatever fastboot is something else. "Fast Startup" is a hybrid suspend option that is enabled by default that must be disabled to share the volume with Ubuntu in dual boot configuration

Comment: Some Windows updates restore FastBoot to the setting Microsoft wants (ON), and you have to turn it OFF again.

Answer (score 0):

Try `ntfsfix /dev/sd*` before mounting it. That checks any file system errors and fixes the disk if it's hibernated so it can be mounted with read-write permissions.